# Unable to resolve domain names from PHP in Apache. Works from command line

Tags: php, apache, ip-address, hostname

we just migrated our production server to a new host (dedicated servers). And now we are unable resolve domain names from PHP pages when loaded from Apache. However, it works fine when we execute the php page from the command line. 
For example, the following PHP code returns the IP address when executed from command line but fails when page is loaded in browser thru Apache.

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.google.com');
echo $ip;
```

Any thoughts? We are running Apache 2.4 on Windows Server 2012.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yea one, where is ___the following PHP file___

Comment: Are you running your own DNS if so it sounds like it may be configured badly

Comment: No. We are not running our own DNS. The PHP script works fine from the command line. It doesnt work when accessed via Apache thru a web browser.